# label rows in top 20% sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming this sample data in a sql table:

```
people   income
Mary     100
Joe      60
Sam      70
Bob      85
Sarah    85
```

I am trying to create a column which will identify each row as within the top 20% of income.  So, the expected output is:

```
people   income   performers
Mary     100      Y
Joe      60       N
Sam      70       N
Bob      85       Y
Sarah    85       Y
```

I have tried TOP (20) PERCENT and a CASE statement, no luck.
Just tried even extracting the top 20% and kept getting errors as well.

In Pandas, I got this, no problem.  In SQL, it's like underwater brain surgery using oven mitts.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (the easiest solution here likely involves the imperative programming extension of your db)

Comment: Good point.  I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: When you say "top 20%" of income, is that 20% of the highest value in the table? Is 100 the largest value possible in the table?

Comment: Yes, assuming 100 is the top income, for example, from there, 80 and up is in the top 20%.  So some will be in that category and some not, just trying to add a column that reflects that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to compare each record to the max value of `income`, you can use a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to compare the current record:

```sql
SELECT people, income,
  CASE 
    WHEN income >= (SELECT MAX(income) FROM Foo) * 0.8 
    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
  END AS performers
FROM Foo;
```

```
people  income  performer
Mary    100     Y
Joe     60      N
Sam     70      N
Bob     85      Y
Sarah   85      Y
```

Comment: @D M thanks for taking a look.  I may be injecting some issues that are not resolvable, but in my actual data, the column I am trying to assign a Y or N from is actually a calculated column   ROUND(SUM(Salary), 2) total_income, When I try to apply your answer and the one above, same error 'Invalid column name 'total_sold''  Perhaps I cannot use a case statement with a calculated column?

Comment: I'm not sure, could you please add the schema of the table and the computed column to the question and I'll take another look?

Comment: Ah, I got it!  Thanks to your suggestion D M it worked!  Amazing stuff there.  But, your concise example made understanding it pretty straightforward.  Thanks again!

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh Good catch

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement

```
select
people,
income,
case when income >= (select max(income) from Table) * .8 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as performer
from Table
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review my question.  Tried your suggestion and received this error.  'Incorrect syntax near 'Yes'  Ideas?  My select statement is using a calculated column to then generate the column with the indentifiers for percentage.  LIke this  SELECT #temp_table.person_id, ROUND(SUM(price),2) total_income,

Comment: Yes thank you @DM I went ahead and updated the code to include the “then”